# nx + nestjs + graphql and code first seems broken, throws 'status is not defined' for a simple health check, repository inside

Tags: nestjs, nrwl-nx, nestjs-graphql

I'm trying to build a monorepo of nestjs + svelte applications using nx, generated all applications and libraries using the CLI/nx commands.

Initially I thought this error is because the model is imported from a shared library but then I moved the definitions to the output of that graphql query right into the root resolver.

[Repository can be found here.](https://github.com/sebastiangug/nx-playground)

Just `pnpm install` and `pnpm start` then go to `localhost:3100/graphql` and run:

```
query {
  getHealth{
    status
  }
}
```

it throws:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "status is not defined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getHealth"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "ReferenceError: status is not defined",
            "    at RootResolver.getHealth (D:\\00 SOFTWARE\\temp\\nx-playground\\dist\\apps\\graphql-server\\webpack:\\nx-playground\\apps\\graphql-server\\src\\app\\resolvers\\root.resolver.ts:23:40)",
            "    at D:\\00 SOFTWARE\\temp\\nx-playground\\node_modules\\.pnpm\\@nestjs+core@9.0.8_j3qpqvsfitzwbryyelxorkuzfa\\node_modules\\@nestjs\\core\\helpers\\external-context-creator.js:70:33",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Any ideas on why this is or how to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Played with your reproduction, in your `@Query()` you have `this.tracer.info(log, 'getHealth', status)`, but you don't define `status` anywhere. Seems that Typescript isn't complaining because `lib.dom.d.ts` has a global `status` value. You should make sure that your Nest projects are using `@types/node` instead of the `lib.dom.d.ts` as it's a Node project.

Removing the `this.tracer` line caused a successful response from the server, so it's just a non-defined variable being referenced